# Two displays one wont turn off

Tags: display

I have two displays and i'd like to shut off the display on my laptop but it won't turn off.  I must be missing something but I don't know what.  I turn it off in the settings menu but it still stays on.  Any help would be great.  My video card is built in from AMD.

Thanks,

Tony

Answer (score 0):

You can setup this at System Settings > Displays.
There should be an option that says "Use this Display".

[image: Display settings]

You can also close your laptop lid while there is an external monitor connected. That will turn off the laptop integrated display and set the external monitor as the main display.

Answer (score 0):

Try '**xrandr --listmonitors**' from a terminal.

You'll see the display names (example eDP-1 or DP-1-1).

For Example DP-1
Now from the command line '**xrandr --output DP-1 --off**'